# DIDISOFT PGP Lib Hangs during decryption of a particular string

Tags: java, encryption, pgp

When I encrypt the following string, apparently the length of the string below is great than 1024 and once encrypted it can decrypt it, but once the string is reduced to less than 1024, it then decrypts the string without hanging

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                + "<FTSingleCreditResponse>\n"
                + "    <Amount>1000.00</Amount>\n"
                + "    <BeneficiaryAccountName>Akogun Olasoji</BeneficiaryAccountName>\n"
                + "    <BeneficiaryAccountNumber>000000020</BeneficiaryAccountNumber>\n"
                + "    <BeneficiaryBankVerificationNumber></BeneficiaryBankVerificationNumber>\n"
                + "    <BeneficiaryKYCLevel>1</BeneficiaryKYCLevel>\n"
                + "    <ChannelCode>12</ChannelCode>\n"
                + "    <DestinationInstitutionCode>999194</DestinationInstitutionCode>\n"
                + "    <NameEnquiryRef>999999200825144654200825144654</NameEnquiryRef>\n"
                + "    <Narration>Transaction from me you</Narration>\n"
                + "    <OriginatorAccountName>Ajao Niyi</OriginatorAccountName>\n"
                + "    <OriginatorAccountNumber>0105498919</OriginatorAccountNumber>\n"
                + "    <OriginatorBankVerificationNumber>10000000002</OriginatorBankVerificationNumber>\n"
                + "    <OriginatorKYCLevel>1</OriginatorKYCLevel>\n"
                + "    <PaymentReference>ref/2015/08/05/val 3</PaymentReference>\n"
                + "    <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>\n"
                + "    <SessionID>999999200827170808200827170807</SessionID>\n"
                + "    <TransactionLocation>6.4300747,3.4110715</TransactionLocation>\n"
                + "</FTSingleCreditResponse>";
```

PGPLib hands when decrypting the encrypted result of the string above.

Below are my encryption and decryption methods using pgpLib

**Encrypt**

```
public String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();
            boolean armor = false;
            boolean withIntegrityCheck = true;

            ByteArrayOutputStream o = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            logger.debug("step 1");
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            logger.debug("step 2");
            if (publicKeyFile == null) {
                publicKeyFile = new File(publicKeyLocation);
            }
            logger.debug("step 3");
            InputStream publicKeyStream = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
            logger.debug("step 4");
            pgp.encryptStream(is, publicKeyLocation, publicKeyStream, o, armor,
                    withIntegrityCheck);
            logger.debug("step 5");
            byte[] body = o.toByteArray();
            int numberRead = body.length;
            logger.debug(" -|- SSModuleClient :: pickMessage :: numberRead: " + numberRead);
            return byte2hex(body);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.debug(" -|- SSModule :: MessageProcessor :: encrypt () :: Error Occurred ..."
                    + ex.getMessage());
            logger.debug("SSModule", ex);
        } catch (PGPException ex) {
            logger.debug(" -|- SSModule :: MessageProcessor :: encrypt () :: Error Occurred ..."
                    + ex.getMessage());
            logger.debug("SSModule", ex);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

**Decrypt**

```
public String decrypt(String text) {

        String decryptedMessage = "";

        try {
            byte[] bytText = hex2byte(text);

            PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

            InputStream iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytText);

            logger.debug("SSModule :: decrypt () :: iStream.available(): "
                    + iStream.available());

            if (privateKeyFile == null) {
                privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyLocation);
            }
            InputStream privateKeyStream = new FileInputStream(privateKeyLocation);
            PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
            OutputStream oStream = new PipedOutputStream(pin);

            logger.debug("text: " + text);

            logger.info("privateKeyPassPhrase: " + privateKeyPassPhrase);

            pgp.decryptStream(iStream, privateKeyStream, getPrivateKeyPassPhrase(),
                    oStream);
            do {
                logger.debug("pin.available(): " + pin.available());
            } while (pin.available() <= 0);
            byte[] body = new byte[pin.available()];
            pin.read(body);
            decryptedMessage = new String(body).toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.debug("SSModule :: MessageProcessor :: decrypt () :: Error Occurred ..."
                    + ex.getMessage());
            logger.debug("SSModule", ex);
        }

        return decryptedMessage;
    }
```

From the decryption method, it does not go beyond the `pgp.decryptStream` it just hangs and does not go further, other strings encrypt and decrypt well but this particular one does not

Comment: Hi Alex, is there any exception or it just hags. And is there any reason why you don't use the PGPLib.encryptString and .decryptString methods instead of the Stream methods?

Comment: @AtanasKrachev it just freezes up with no exceptions. I resulted to updating the library and using the ‘encryptString’

Comment: Alex, if you still have any issues you can contact DidiSoft directly at https://www.didisoft.com/support/